# Reset console in windows

Tags: windows

I messed up my console while screwing with its settings is their anyway to reset the console to its defaults and if not could someone please post the console defaults like width font etc

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked in the registry : `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`?

This is what I have...

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
"ColorTable01"=dword:00800000
"ColorTable02"=dword:00008000
"ColorTable03"=dword:00808000
"ColorTable04"=dword:00000080
"ColorTable05"=dword:00800080
"ColorTable06"=dword:00008080
"ColorTable07"=dword:00c0c0c0
"ColorTable08"=dword:00808080
"ColorTable09"=dword:00ff0000
"ColorTable10"=dword:0000ff00
"ColorTable11"=dword:00ffff00
"ColorTable12"=dword:000000ff
"ColorTable13"=dword:00ff00ff
"ColorTable14"=dword:0000ffff
"ColorTable15"=dword:00ffffff
"CursorSize"=dword:00000019
"EnableColorSelection"=dword:00000000
"ExtendedEditKey"=dword:00000000
"ExtendedEditKeyCustom"=dword:00000000
"FontFamily"=dword:00000000
"FontSize"=dword:00000000
"FontWeight"=dword:00000000
"FullScreen"=dword:00000000
"HistoryBufferSize"=dword:00000032
"HistoryNoDup"=dword:00000000
"InsertMode"=dword:00000001
"LoadConIme"=dword:00000001
"NumberOfHistoryBuffers"=dword:00000004
"PopupColors"=dword:000000f5
"QuickEdit"=dword:00000000
"ScreenBufferSize"=dword:012c0050
"ScreenColors"=dword:00000007
"TrimLeadingZeros"=dword:00000000
"WindowSize"=dword:00190050
"WordDelimiters"=dword:00000000
"CurrentPage"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: how to i get to that registry

Comment: open a command prompt, and type `regedit`

Comment: thanks i got it to work i just deleted all my registrys for thee console

Answer (score 2):

My defaults are

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!